# Java spark-submit: Exception thrown in awaitResult

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, exception

I am trying to submit an application to Spark through ./spark-submit.

I build a jar with java and the codes as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;


public class SimpleApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logFile = "/user/root/simple/1.txt";  
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache(); 

        long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) {
                return s.contains("a"); 
            }
        }).count();

        long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) {
                return s.contains("b");
            }
        }).count();

        System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
    }
}
```

When I submitted it to local:

```
./spark-submit --class "com.mycompany.simpleapp.SimpleApp" --master local[4] /home/mapr/SimpleApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

things work well.

But when I tried to submit it to Spark standalone cluster:

```
./spark-submit --class "com.mycompany.simpleapp.SimpleApp" --master spark://10.XXX.XXX.XX:7077 /home/mapr/SimpleApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I got the "Exception thrown in awaitResult" as below:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.sca                                                                                                                                                             la:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.sca                                                                                                                                                             la:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.s                                                                                                                                                             cala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyO                                                                                                                                                             rElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyO                                                                                                                                                             rElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$an                                                                                                                                                             onfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51                                                                                                                                                             1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                                                                                             java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                                                                                             .java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.XXX.XXX.XX:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(T                                                                                                                                                             ransportClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(T                                                                                                                                                             ransportClientFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala                                                                                                                                                             :197)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /10.XXX.XXX.XX:7077
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717                                                                                                                                                             )
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocke                                                                                                                                                             tChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConne                                                                                                                                                             ct(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.jav                                                                                                                                                             a:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEve                                                                                                                                                             ntLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.ja                                                                                                                                                             va:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThread                                                                                                                                                             EventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

The spark version in java library:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1-mapr-1707</version>
        </dependency>
```

The spark version of the cluster:
[spark version of the cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJlj0.png)

I think I don't have the version mismatch problem.

Can anyone tell what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Check if you are redirecting to the right port and you have right permission it is more towards connection problem . because Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.XXX.XXX.XX:7077   ....Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /10.XXX.XXX.XX:7077

Comment: i think your mapr cluster runs a different Spark version (perhaps 1.6?): your driver code uses Spark 2.0.1, which (I think) doesn't even use Akka, and the message on the master says something about failing to decode Akka protocol - can you check the version used on master ?

Comment: @Indrajit Swain thanks for the hint, my cluster Spark version is 2.0.1-mapr-1707 as shown in the picture link I attached in the question. I think I have used the same version for the java library.

Answer (score -1):

For troubleshooting;

1. ensure the master is up & running,

   eg. lsof -i -P | grep 7077

this command lists the open Internet files without conversion of port names, and search for 7077 string. Run this command on a terminal at which the spark master runs.

2. ensure there is no firewall blocking,

   eg. telnet 10.XXX.XXX.XX 7077

this command tries to open a connecton to desired address and port. It prints a success message or timeout or a "connection refused" message.

hope this helps,